# Submitting forms using jquery $.ajax - oly the first submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a problem with submitting AJAX forms - using [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).

My forms are in `div#upform` and when I'm trying to submit any of them via `$.ajax` it submits only the first one, here's the code:

```
$(function() {  
    $(".button").click(function() {  
        var txt = $(".tekst#test").val();  
        var dataString = 'tekst='+ tekscior;

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "upload/base",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function() {  
                $('#upform').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                $('#message').html("<h2>described!</h2>")  
                    .append("<p>thanks!</p>")  
                    .hide()  
                    .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
                        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='http://artivia-dev2/i/check.png' />");  
                    });  
            }  
        });  
        return false; 
    });  
});
```

AND Here are my forms:

```
<!-- ONLY THIS ONE IS SUBMITTED, EVEN WHEN I'M SUBMITTING THE SECOND ONE! -->
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div id="upform">
        <form name="contact" action="">  
            <input type="text" value="TESTFORM" class="tekst" id="test">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Send" />
        <form>
    </div> 

    <div class="slidingDiv">
        <div id="upform">
            <form name="contact" action=""> 
                <input type="text" value="TESTFORM" class="tekst" id="test">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Send" />
            <form>
        </div>
```

**@@UPDATE**

Problem, when I submit one form - it's great - but when after this one submit I want to submit the second - the data is submitted correctly, but the success messages are refreshed in both forms, that's the fix, which I've triend to use, but it doesn't work:

```
    $.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "upload/base",  
          data: dataString,  
          success: function() {  

        upform.html("<div class='message'></div>");  

             var mess =  $(this).closest('.message');

             mess.html("<h2>Described</h2>")  
            .append("<p>Thanks!</p>")  
            .hide()  
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
            mess.append("<img id='checkmark' src='http://ar-dev2/i/check.png' />");  
            });  


          }  
        });
```

Comment: avoid using the same id for elements eg(#upform). ids should be unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should not use same `id` to multiple element. Instead of that you may use `class` or `name` or `data` attribute.

```
$(".button").click(function() {  

   var upform = $(this).closest('.upform'); // keep reference of upform

    var txt = $(this).prev(".tekst").val();  // this will retrieve the value of input
                                             // nearest to the button

    var dataString = 'tekst='+ tekscior;

    ......

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",  
      url: "upload/base",  
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        upform.html();
        .....
      }
    });
});
```

#### Problem with `var txt = $(".tekst#test");` selector:

It has been started searching from top and when it found a match it stop journey and return the value and you always get the value of first one. If you use

`var txt = $(".tekst");` without `id`, you will face the same problem.

Comment: I changed the ID upform into class upform, added your code and work well - but I have one more question - you see that ajax method gives the info about successing displaying message div (i changed id into class) but it displays after one submit on all of the forms - and the $this.prev - doesn't work - how to fix it?                                                                  Ofc I accepted your answer - it helped me a lot : ]

Comment: Problem with sending data is solved, now I have problem with displaying success message : )

Answer (score 2):

IDs are singular. You can not have the same id on the page more than once!

If you want to repeat identifiers, use name.

Comment: +1, but I'd suggest using classes for repeat identifiers, over name attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using different ids for both the forms. Both your forms have the same id `upform`